# Basic MVC based Swing application

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jgoodies

So I hit the following problem: I want to initializate the Swing constructor with a controller instance from my `App` class. That is the place I init the repo and controller. When i want to pass to the swing `Gui` class, the controller parameter I realized it has its own main method.

Could you please check the code and tell me if this is the correct approach? 'Cause I'm uncertain, and i can't find a basic example from a TUI app to a GUI app. Thank you!

> App.java

```
package app;

import repository.*;
import view.View_gui;
import controller.*;

public class App{
    RepoInterface ri;
    ControllerInterface c;
    View_gui gui;

    public App() {
        ri = new Repo();
        c = new Controller(ri);
        gui = new View_gui(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
    }
}
```

> View_gui.java

```
package view;

import controller.*;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class View_gui {

    private JFrame frame;
    private static ControllerInterface ci; //added the variable

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    View_gui window = new View_gui(ci); // parametrizied
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public View_gui(ControllerInterface c) {
        ci = c;                          // add + param by me
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Countries");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Country");

        JLabel lblCapital = new JLabel("Capital");

        JLabel lblArea = new JLabel("Area");


    }
}
```

Comment: 1) does your code work? Are you able to see a GUI? 2) What is a TUI application? 3) What is your main question? What are you asking us about?

Comment: code works, i see the gui... TUI is textbased interface, is this aproache the coorect one for a swing app?

Comment: It looks OK, but the reason I asked number 1) is that I don't see where you call `setVisible(true)` on the view's top level window, when you start from your App class.

Comment: there is `  window.frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: That's in the View_gui's main method, a method which should never be called. The App main method should be called instead.

Comment: TUI is Text User Interface, the opposite of GUI